# Importing lua modules and using them with lua pandoc filter

Tags: lua, pandoc

Pandoc natively supports lua filter by its --lua-filter argument. 
However, I am wondering however what version of lua is it using and whether it is possible to import lua modules such as luacom (which i believe relies on C code) into it.
This is part of my investigation to create a filter that reads excel worksheet and converts them to pandoc table.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is generally possible to check the Lua version by running `print(_VERSION)`. I.e., running this in your shell should work:

```sh
pandoc --lua-filter <(echo 'print(_VERSION)') <<< ''
```

Older pandoc versions could be compiled with any of Lua 5.1, Lua 5.2, Lua 5.3, or LuaJIT. However, maintaining compatibility was burdensome, so the maintainer of the [HsLua](https://hslua.github.io) package used by pandoc (i.e., I), stopped supporting older versions about a year ago. If you are using pandoc 2.3.1 or later, pandoc is guaranteed to contain Lua 5.3.x.

Loading pure Lua libraries will be no problem and should work just as with a plain Lua executable. The only problem can be that the default `LUA_PATH` set in pandoc differs from that used in other programs. This can happen if pandoc has not been compiled against the system-wide Lua version. [LuaRocks](https://luarocks.org) can help there, just run `eval "$(luarocks path)"`.

Same as with pure Lua libraries, C Lua libraries should just work if pandoc has been compiled as a non-static binary. However, non-Windows binaries provided on the pandoc website and on GitHub are static, and dynamic loading of C libraries will **not** work.

We [maintain Alpine-based Docker images](https://github.com/pandoc/dockerfiles), `pandoc/core` and `pandoc/latex`, which are compiled against the system-wide Lua version. This can be a good option if your platform's package manager doesn't ship a recent pandoc version, can't use the statically compiled binary, and you don't want to compile pandoc yourself. If you'd like to see support for other base image like Ubuntu, just raise a ticket.

Comment: Thanks tarleb. Is there a guide/script to compiling the pandoc to a non-static binary? I am not really familiar with docker (and I am using windows) so I am more inclined with just compiling it .

Comment: The Windows binary is dynamically linked, no need to compile it.